# How to delete log results from Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-rc

When I build my test I generate a server log file, which is good. The problem is that after several runs it becomes very long and it's hard to get orientate with it.

Is there any way to delete this file every run and than create it?

Comment: What do you use to generate this log file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin), with that you can add a build environment configuration to clean up specific files, in *Advanced...* panel you can limit deletion to certain patterns, e.g. `**/*.log`.

If your log file is managed outside your job's workspace, add a new build step at beginning of type *Execute shell script* to manually delete the log file. This works with jobs of type freestyle.